# Selecting max of a sum of two columns

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table comparisons. If I run

```
SELECT comparisonID,stu1Vers,stu2Vers,stu1,stu2 
    from comparisons 
    WHERE stu1!=stu2 and assignmentid=9;
```

I get something like:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+------+------+
| comparisonID | stu1Vers | stu2Vers | stu1 | stu2 |
+--------------+----------+----------+------+------+
|          287 |       12 |        2 |    1 |    6 |
|          286 |       12 |        1 |    1 |    6 |
|          276 |       11 |        2 |    1 |    6 |
|          275 |       11 |        1 |    1 |    6 |
|          266 |       10 |        2 |    1 |    6 |
|          265 |       10 |        1 |    1 |    6 |
|          257 |        9 |        2 |    1 |    6 |
|          256 |        9 |        1 |    1 |    6 |
...
|          391 |       19 |        1 |    1 |    6 |
|          392 |       19 |        2 |    1 |    6 |
+--------------+----------+----------+------+------+
```

I'd like to select the entire row where stu1Vers+stu2Vers is the maximum. I keep trying something along the lines of

```
select c.comparisonid,c.stu1vers,c.stu2vers,max(totvers) 
from comparisons as c join 
    (select comparisonid, stu1vers+stu2vers as totvers 
    from comparisons where stu1!=stu2 group by comparisonid) as cm 
on c.comparisonid = cm.comparisonid and c.stu1vers+c.stu2vers = cm.totvers;
```

but that returns a rather random assortment of things:

```
+--------------+----------+----------+--------------+
| comparisonid | stu1vers | stu2vers | max(totvers) |
+--------------+----------+----------+--------------+
|          220 |        1 |        1 |           21 |
+--------------+----------+----------+--------------+
```

I'm trying to get row 392 in the first table.

Comment: What should happen if there are multiple rows with the same maximum value? Return all of them, or just one? If the latter, which one?

Comment: There's actually another two columns in the table, one each for stu1 and stu2's ids. So return all of them, but grouped by stu1 or stu2). max(stu1vers+stu2vers) is guaranteed to be unique for any student for any assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want all the rows when there are multiple rows with the same maximum value, then you can use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE stu1Vers + stu2Vers = (SELECT MAX(stu1Vers + stu2Vers) FROM Table1)
```

Including your condition:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
WHERE stu1Vers + stu2Vers = (
    SELECT MAX(stu1Vers + stu2Vers)
    FROM Table1
    WHERE stu1!=stu2 and assignmentid=9
) AND stu1!=stu2 and assignmentid=9
```

Result:

```
392, 19, 2, 1, 6
```

Regarding your update to the question, I'm not sure what you mean to return all the rows grouped by stu1 and stu2. Perhaps you mean ordered by these columns? If so, add `ORDER BY stu1, stu2` to the query.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 comparisonid, stu1vers, stu2vers, stu1Vers + stu2Vers AS MaxValue
  FROM comparisons
 ORDER BY MaxValue DESC
```

Comment: Note: This will only return one of the matches, not all of them as requested in the update to the question.

Comment: And `TOP 1` is not how you return one row in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this?

```
 SELECT comparisonID,stu1Vers,stu2Vers,stu1,stu2, max(stu1Vers + stu2Vers) as maximum
     from comparisons 
     WHERE stu1!=stu2 and assignmentid=9 order by maximum desc limit 1;
```